# How to write the content of a unknown shell variable to stdout in a safe way

Tags: shell, echo

I only know what I have read so far, and I am confused about how to actually echo a variable as is.

- `echo "$var"` might fail if `var='-n'`
- `printf '%s\n' "$var"` might fail because of shell not implementig `printf`
- `echo -- "$var"` might fail because it is a gnu extension

So if i would have to guess:

`echo x"$var"|sed 's#^x##1'` would be the only way, but I have never encountered that pattern. Why?

---

As a concrete question:

```
for source; do
  target="$(echo "$source"|sed 's#[^a-z0-9]\+#.#')"
  # do stuff with $source and $target
done
```

Does this work, or could someone "hack" / "break" my script by putting a file named '-n' somewhere, assuming my script is executed by some `my_script *` cron?

How do I write `echo "$var"` so it does not break?

Comment: Could you give an example of a shell that fails doing the right thing with `printf '%s\n' "$var"`?  If the shell does not implement `printf` (as with `sh`/`ksh` on OpenBSD, for example), there will be an external utility that would be used.

Comment: If the shell doesn't implement `printf`, it's not a POSIX shell. Use `printf`.

Comment: `printf` is actually much more portable (in terms of presence of standard-mandated guarantees around its behavior) than `echo`. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html; to quote from the former: *It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.*

Comment: One more note: This is one of those basic things even `shellcheck -ssh` won't catch. It might be because it would be unreasonable if shellcheck would warn about any use of echo without fixed values.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this work, or could someone "hack" / "break" my script by putting
>   a file named '-n' somewhere?

There is nothing wrong with:

```
target="$(echo "$source"|sed 's#[^a-z0-9]\+#.#')"
```

What is happening:

- `"$(...)"` is a *command substitution* which will substitute the results of the command within as the value -- in which case the result is assigned to `target`.
- `echo "$source"|sed 's#[^a-z0-9]\+#.#'` simply pipes the output of `echo` (e.g. what is in `source`) to `sed` for the simple substitution of *every character not lowercase or a digit followed by +* with a *period* <sup>**1**</sup>. Note: the quotes `".."` around `$source` ARE proper within the command substitution.
- There is no inherent reason assigning `-n` to a variable will cause any mischief. What you do with the variable is another question, but suffice it to say it is hard to see any problem.
- "POSIX-shell's out there not implementing `printf`" -- Huh? Any shell not implementing `printf` would be more an exception rather than the rule. See [printf - The Open Group Library](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) that is POSIX.

If you are attempting to `printf` output that begins with `'-'` simply precede the output with `"--"` to indicate *End-of-Options* before the string your want to print and things will go fine. With your example of `"-n"`, `printf` is about the only way you will output a variable beginning with the single `'-'`, for example:

```
$ t="-n"

$ printf -- "%s\n" "$t"
-n
```

(**note:** you don't have to include `"--"` in `printf "%s\n" "$var"`, the only time you **must** include it is with `printf -- "-foo\n"` or you will receive an `"invalid option error"`.

For `echo` you can enable interpretation of backslash escapes with `-e` and include a *backspace*, e.g.

```
$ echo -e " \b$t"
-n
```

I think that has covered all issues. If not, let me know. Also, if you have any additional questions, drop a comment below or edit and add to your question.

**footnotes:**

1. note: `+` isn't part of *basic regular expressions* and it need not be escaped, but if there is any question, it is safer to include in a *character class* of its own, e.g. `[^a-z0-9][+]`.

Comment: why do you assume that `var='-n'; echo "$var"` is not doing something unexpected compared to `var='-x'; echo "$var"`, have you tried both?

Comment: Because `echo` is writing to `stdout` it is outputting `$var`. Without the `-e` and backspace the worst that can happen is `-n` is interpreted as `"do not output the trailing newline"` in which case the `-n` itself is consumed by `echo`. (and yes, I've tried both). Either `echo -e " \b-n"` or `echo -e " \n$var"`. When dealing with the `'-'` as the leading character, you will need to check whether the first character with, e.g. a parameter expansion in advanced shells, or with `expr substring "$var" 1 1` in POSIX

Comment: Note: `expr substring "$var" 1 1` should be `expr substr "$var" 1 1` (note `substr` not `substring`)

Comment: Better yet, if you are using `echo` and it is unclear, then use a `case` statement on the output of `expr substr "$var" 1 2` and test whether the results is `"-n"`, `"-e"` or `"-E"` and modify your `echo` use to avoid having the variable consumed as an option. In that case, `printf` is by far your best option.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer (+1) I still think you are not taking the issue serious enough. Having a wrong/empty value in a variable seems to be just a matter of "we cross that bridge if we ever even encounter it"

Comment: So what would be the right/best/saved way to write it?

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be flippant, but you don't really have a scripting problem as much as you have a *variable content* problem. The trick is to identify the content of the variable *before* you use it in a way that could cause problems. That's just basic **validation**. Now granted the `-foo` is somewhat a corner case in shell, but that is precisely the reason POSIX provided `"--"` to signify *End-of-option* input. I don't take the issue lightly, and having a variable consumed as an option is indeed a big problem, but the way to avoid it is to validate.

Comment: One more question: do you realy need to write `printf '%s\n' -foo` as `printf -- '%s\n' -foo`? I thought printf only recognizes parameters if the precede the pattern.

Comment: Personally, I would use `printf -- "%s\n" "$var"`. If you have a shell that doesn't provide `printf` (and in 20 years I haven't found one, but not that they don't exist), then you will just have to check whether what you are using begins with `'-'` and validate it isn't an option to `echo` if you are piping with `echo`. (this is just one area where `echo` is quirky - technical term)

Comment: And, you don't have to include `"--"` in `printf "%s\n" "$var"`, the only time you must include it is with `printf -- "-foo\n"` or you will receive an `invalid option` error.

Comment: No problem, this is actually a really good question that uncovers a rarely addressed issue with `echo` and `printf`. That's just a shortcoming of `echo` more than anything else.

Comment: `printf '%s\n'` does not need `--` as `%s` does not start with `-`.

Comment: That's what I said two comments above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, but the _answer_ still states that the `--` are needed if the value of the _variable_ starts with a dash.

Comment: This should probably moved to chat: normal sed needs 'x\+' to indicate the same as sed -e 'x+' (one or more of x). but that part was only an example, because i know that general "how do I do it right" questions are not welcome on SO. On SO it is not a "real" problem if it alreadz works, but might be written in a way that it would fail later, or pose a vunerabilty, So I just picked (actully i maded it up one on the fly, because the real onece where to complex) one.

Comment: Try this: `echo '_xxx_x_x+_x' | sed 's#x+#T#g'
` and this `echo '_xxx_x_x+_x' | sed 's#x\+#T#g`

Comment: So you are saying printf isn't not implemented by all shells I should ever worry about? Not directed at you, but I am worried about the common "Huh? Any shell not being bash, that's almost impossible"-attitude I encounter to often.

Comment: @Sam, if you're worried about incompatibilities between shells, that's a reason to avoid `echo`, not a reason to avoid `printf`. And as a matter of habit/practice, the reference source to determine which behavior you can and can't trust to be portable is the POSIX specification -- the POSIX sh spec came out in 1992, and SunOS is the *only* major operating system I know to have shipped a noncompliant default `sh` inside the last two decades.

Comment: @Sam, ...btw, I don't think it's fair to argue that "how to do it right" questions are innately unwelcome. We do insist that questions be based on "a real problem that you face", but if that "real problem" is that you need to support all POSIX-compliant platforms (and so want to write code that, f/e, will run anywhere `sed` implements only baseline BRE without any vendor extensions -- such as the common add-a-backslash-to-access-ERE-extensions GNUism), that's legit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thx, to be fair, I don't "need" to support all platforms, just want to avoid future trouble with new environments, I ran into those problems only twice so far. And I was always taught that it might be a security concern (mostly with the '\n' vs '\0' issue). From all of the comment, inducing yours can I assume `printf '%s\n' "$var"` is the "best" (most likely not to have compatibility issues) way to use a variable in a pipe?